# Python Jinja2 Google App Engine: getting value from HTML select

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, html-select

I am building a webapp using Python, Jinja2 and Google App Engine/Datastore.

When trying to implement a dropdown for a user to give one of several pre-defined inputs to the datastore, the value from the HTML select is not saved to the datastore. And after having used a long time looking for an answer, I still have not found a solution.
The value I want them to give me is for the selections in lamptype.
Everything else works fine and if I enter single values instead of the multiple choice selection, it works fine. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Can anyone help me?

My HTML:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <label>
                <div>Lampens Mærke(skriv ukendt hvis du ikke kender mærket):</div>
                <input type="text" name="brand" value="{{brand}}">
            </label>
            <label>
                <div>Lampens Pæretype(vælg type):</div>
                <select>
                    <option name="lamptype" value="LED">LED</option>
                    <option name="lamptype" value="gloedepare">glødepære</option>
                    <option name="lamptype" value="halogen">halogen</option>
                    <option name="lamptype" value="anden">anden</option>
                </select>
            </label>
            <label>
                <div>Lampens model(eks nummer, type el. lign.):</div>
                <input type="text" name="model" value="{{model}}">
            </label>
            <label>
                <div>Lampens effekt i Watt:</div>
                <input type="number" name="watt" value="{{watt}}">
            </label>
            <label>
                <div>Beskrivelse af lampen(ikke obligatorisk):</div>
                <textarea name="description">{{description}}</textarea>
            </label>
            <!-- <label>
                <div>Billede af lampen(ikke obligatorisk):</div>
                <input type="file" name="image">
            </label> -->
            <div class="error">{{error}}</div>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

My Lamp class in my main python file:

```
class Lamp(db.Model):
"""class that creates the basic database structure for Lamp"""
    owner = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    lamptype = db.StringProperty()
    brand = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    model = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    watt = db.IntegerProperty(required=True)
    description = db.TextProperty()
    image = db.BlobProperty()
    booked = db.BooleanProperty()
```

my python code for retrieving user input and putting it into the datastore:

```
#Class below handles new instances of LAMP.
class NewLamp(Handler):
"""class that renders a page for creating a new Lamp instance"""
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            self.render("newlamp.html")
        else:
            error = "Du skal vaere logget ind for at oprette ting!"
            self.render('login.html', error=error)

    def post(self):
        if not self.user:
            return self.redirect("/mypage/login")

        owner = self.user.name
        brand = self.request.get("brand")
        lamptype = self.request.get("lamptype")
        model = self.request.get("model")
        watt = int(self.request.get("watt"))
        # image = self.request.get("image")
        description = self.request.get("description")

        if brand and model and watt:
            l = Lamp(parent = blog_key(), owner = owner, brand = brand, lamptype = lamptype,
            model = model, watt = watt, description = description)
            l.put()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            self.redirect("/mypage/mythings")
        else:
            error = "Du skal udfylde alle obligatorisk felter!"
            return self.render("newlamp.html", brand = brand, model = model,
            watt = watt, description = description, error = error)
```

Comment: First of all, your HTML doesn't appear to allow multiple choices in the SELECT element. You would need to add the MULTIPLE attribute to enable that.

Secondly, if you DO make multiple selections, how would that be represented in your database?

Comment: I made myself unclear. I give the user multiple choices, of which they can choose one. I want them to choose only one thing. I have edited my question to make that clear. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a name attribute to your `select` tag like this:

```
<select name="lamptype">
```

When you submit a form, only data that has a `name` attribute is included in the post.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this earlier, without effect. The problem was that I had a spelling mistake for lamptype in another function, preventing it from being written to the datastore properly. Rookie mistake. Thank you very much!